# PAssing an array to a hash table, single item array failing

Tags: powershell

I have the file below, which accepts an array of servers. Works well when there are multiple items in the array, and I note the answer that a user suggested in a previous post, which was to put a , in front of the values if its a single item array, trying that with a hash table just doesnt worked. I have tried various options without much luck.

```
param ([array[]]$servers = $(throw "Input array of servers.") , $folder )

$x = $servers
$k = 'serverid','servername','locationid','appid'    # key names correspond to data positions in each array in $x
 $h = @{}
      
      
 For($i=0;$i -lt $x[0].length; $i++){
     $x |
         ForEach-Object{
             [array]$h.($k[$i]) += [string]$_[$i]
         }
               
               
 } 

 $all_server_ids = $h['Serverid']

 foreach ($server_id in $all_server_ids)
{
    $severid = $h["serverid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
    $servername =  $h["servername"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]
    $locationid =  $h["locationid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_id)]

    Write-Output "This $severid and this $servername and this $locationid"

}
```

Running the below.
.\test.ps1 -servers  ,('72','Server1\DEV2','1.0') -folder "F:\files"

Getting the error

```
Cannot index into a null array.
+     $servername =  $h["servername"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_i ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
 
Cannot index into a null array.
+     $locationid =  $h["locationid"][$all_server_ids.indexof($server_i ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

The issue here is that, I need the script to work with multiple items in the array or a single item.

Comment: I see you’re still making this way harder on yourself than it has to be. Have you not looked into objects with properties? You can pass those around so much easier without all this complicated array manipulation

Comment: I am constrained by the limitations of Powershell Workflows, and objects with properties does not work with that unless its inline which defeats the purpose. Is there any other way to deal with single array entries.

Custom class doesnt work either once it goes into a workflow block.

Comment: @mklement0 Any ideas here please ?